# Can anyone recommend a gem or plugin that handles @mentions, twitter style, that I can use in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tagging

I'm looking for a gem or plugin for Rails that can handle twitter style @mentions. Googling for a bit didn't turn up anything, but I wanted to make sure before I roll my own.

Thanks for looking =)

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb) gem.